# Explicit request for collaboration/support in publications

Tags: publications, collaboration, data, outreach

If I am publishing a conference paper and/or journal article which is about an ongoing, larger project, **is it acceptable or even heard of to not only announce expected future work but also to explicitly request collaboration/support regarding said future work?** — since the quality of my work (and the work of many others) is directly influenced by the amount and quality of the data available to work with, I would like to polish a framework which I use to collect data for a particular phenomenon of interest into one which is even more easily set-up and executed than it is now. Of course, this could also be then used for other people to easily collect the same sort of data... and so it would be nice if other parties interested in the work did so and we ended up pooling our data together.

I haven't seen this sort of implicit "I only have so much time to run experiments so it'd be totally awesome if you guys did it too", so I'm not sure if it's just not done that commonly or if it's not "a thing" at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be totally fine to request collaborations, and my colleagues and I actually did it in a paper. We wrote in the conclusions the following announcement:

The authors welcome collaborations from QHARS manufacturers to analyse further cases of practical interest.

Did it work? Yes, but we are in a small field and this probably makes it easier to collaborate.